# Form element with multiple rows

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I'm trying to create a form which loads the number of users stored in an array. The design looks like this:

[image: GUI Design Image]

How do I create the element in which the data from the different users are shown? I have absolutely no clue on which element to use for that one. What element do I use to get a likewise layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widget is called JTable. See some information here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html